# How to change text in the component base on the project I runs?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I build `auth` lib in my nx monorepo.

The `auth` lib contains `LoginComponent` (smart) and `LoginFormComponent` (dumb).

And I load the lib as lazy by using `loadChildren` to load `auth.module` and inside this module I have a child route to the `LoginComponent` which have `LoginFormComponent`.

Inside the `LoginFormComponent` I have text: "Login to my awesome app".

```
<h1>Login to my awesome app</h1>
<form...>
```

The problem is when I want to add another angular application and use this auth components and functionality.

So when I use the auth from the new application, I'm getting the text: "Login to my awesome app".

For the existing app the text should be: "Login to my awesome app".

And for new app should be: "Login to ng app".

I have only one `auth` lib with one of login component.

So I looking for angular way to deal with such senario.

I was think about duplicate the component but it's not feel right. or to use i18n but not sure because it's for langs, or using `forRoot` and pass the providers with the text? using tokens with inject?

What the ways I can do to change the text? How to handle this issue? is it solution to angular for this senario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can understand your situation. Here is what you should do. I am assuming that you have created a `@shared/auth` lib under `nx` monorepo. The `auth` lib contains the `LoginFormComponent`.

You should exploit `ForRoot` and `@Inject()` to achieve the same.

**auth.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  // all imports etc
})
export class AuthModule {
  static forRoot(appName: string): ModuleWithProviders<AuthModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: AuthModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: APP_NAME, useValue: appName }
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

To avoid any circular dependency while importing `APP_NAME`, create a file as

**config.ts**

```
export const APP_NAME = new InjectionToken<string>('APP_NAME_PARAM');
```

Lets go your `LoginFormComponent`

**LoginFormComponent.component.ts**

```
export class LoginFormComponent{
 
  public appName: string;
  
 constructor(@Inject(APP_NAME) clientAppName: string){
     this.appName = clientAppName;
  }

}
```

**login.component.html**

```
<h1>Login to {{appName}} app</h1>
```

---

Now, we are all set. Only thing left to do, is to use `AuthModule` in our `app.module.ts`

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({ 
   imports: [
      AuthModule.forRoot("Super Awesome")
   ]
})
export class AppModule
```

---

This can help you reuse the `AuthModule` in other apps as well. You just need create a `constant` file for each app library and then move `Super Awesome` into that constant for better readability.

It may not be completely relevant but, you can check  [this article for more understanding of ForRoot and InjectionToken](https://shashankvivek-7.medium.com/forroot-injectiontoken-in-action-angular-c2bab9959207)

I have extensively used it in my Nx monorepo projects. Its a standard way.